# Why does this error exist: "Invariant Violation: Cannot update during an existing state transition"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I seem to be running into this error in a large application (but I'm not exactly sure where):

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: setState(...): Cannot update
>   during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render
>   methods should be a pure function of props and state.

I suspect it might be the result of using `setState` inside of `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Which leads me to my real question: why does this error exist? Is there some conceptual reason I'm missing why ReactJS doesn't just queue state and prop changes? I'm guessing if there is a reason, it has to do with application complexity and/or avoiding race conditions...

My next question then would be: what is the proper way to update a component outside of React (during some asynchronous event for example) so that this error doesn't occur?

**Edit:**

After some digging into this issue further, it appears the culprit is actually the underlying platform I'm using (ElectronJS, formally Atom Shell). Basically, ElectronJS combines Chromium and NodeJS together. I was using a NodeJS API to do something asynchronous and it appears when that finished, ElectronJS would just return back to the call stack where it left off, bypassing the event loop altogether and thus causing a race condition with React.

Comment: React will, if neccessary, batch `setState` calls.

Comment: Hi jameslk, I got the same issue with React + Electron, and the error keep showing. Seems that it will not break the app but still quite annoying. Have you figure out a way to fix that?

Comment: Got something working with `setImmediate( // the function that may call setState)`

Comment: @fraserxv My solutions was similar. It was originating from the library *request.js*, which uses the node http library underneath. I basically had to put a `setTimeout` of `0` (same as `setImmediate`) inside the response callback and the problem went away.

Comment: FYI, I reported the issue on Electron's Github a while back but it was left as a wontfix. "In Electron the task queue of Node.js and the task queue of browser are independent, so there is no guarantee that tasks of setTimeout and Node.js APIs would run in sequence. Also the web standard never guarantees the sequence of setTimeout callbacks, so I think current behavior is fine." Here's the specific issue: https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/2239

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is that `setState` will cause a re-render (potentially, depending on `shouldComponentUpdate`). If you had a `setState` call within the `render` function, it would trigger yet another render. You'd likely end up in an infinite loop of re-renderings.  There's nothing that stops you from using `setState` as a result of some asynchronous operation (in fact it's very common). It's fine just as long as it's not in the `render` or some other lifecycle method of a component that is run on a state update (`shouldComponentUpdate` being another as you'd end up with an infinite loop in the same way).

Comment: What if it must be inside render? I mean I would still get an error which can not be prevented but the only solution is to put an if statement to stop the infinite for loop

Answer (score -3):

One way to achieve this is to use the Flux pattern and have your timeouts trigger changes in a store. This will cause the changes to propagate to interested components as part of their lifecycle.