# Cannot update during an existing state transition - Not using any illegal setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Some one Please Help me with this error
 ***Cannot update during an existing state transition***

When I am rendering this I'm getting error like below

> Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within
>   `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be
>   a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an
>   anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

I have tried putting ***this.props.ifListChanged(this);***  this code inside the componentWillUpdate and componentDidUpadate but it is taking too much time but without errors(almost 2 mins).

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItemComponent from './ListItem.jsx';
import DropDownButtonComponent from './DropDownButton.jsx';
import DropDownStyle from '../../../../css/sass/drop-down.scss';

module.exports = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function () {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  },
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      open: false,
      //listItems: this.props.listItems,
      selectedItems:[],
      title: this.props.dropdownTitle
    }
  },
  handleItemClick: function (item) {
    var selectedItems = [];
    if(this.props.multiple == true){
      selectedItems = this.state.selectedItems;
      if(selectedItems.indexOf(item)==-1){
        selectedItems.push(item);
      }else{
        selectedItems.splice(selectedItems.indexOf(item),1)
      }
      this.setState({
        title: this.state.selectedItems.length+" selected",
        selectedItems: selectedItems
      });
    } else{
      selectedItems = [];
      selectedItems.push(item);
      this.setState({
        title: item,
        selectedItems: selectedItems,
        open: false
      });
    }
    //this.sendStateToParent();
  },
  sendStateToParent: function(){
    this.props.ifListChanged(this);
  },
  handleTextChange: function (event) {
    var filteredItems = [];
    this.props.listItems.map(function(item){
      if(item.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) != -1){
        filteredItems.push(item);
      }
    },this);
    this.setState({
      listItems: filteredItems
    });
  },
  clearSelected: function(){
    this.setState({
      title: this.props.dropdownTitle,
      selectedItems: [],
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    this.props.ifListChanged(this);
    var index = 0;
    var list=[];
    if (this.state.listItems != undefined) {
      list = this.state.listItems.map(function (item) {
        return (
          <ListItemComponent
            key={index++}
            item={item}
            whenItemClicked={this.handleItemClick}
            className={this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item) != -1 ? "active" : ""}
          />);
      }.bind(this));
    } else {
      list = this.props.listItems.map(function (item) {
        return (
          <ListItemComponent
            key={index++}
            item={item}
            whenItemClicked={this.handleItemClick}
            className={this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item) != -1 ? "active" : ""}
          />);
      }.bind(this));
    }

    return <div className="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
      <DropDownButtonComponent
        whenClicked={this.handleClick}
        title={this.state.title}
      />
      <ul className={"dropdown-menu inner dropdown-menu " + (this.state.open ? "show" : "") }>
        {this.props.search? <li><input type="text" style={{margin:"auto", maxWidth:"96%"}} onChange={this.handleTextChange} placeholder="Search"/></li> :""}
        <li className="disabled"><a>Select from below list {this.props.multiple ? <i title="clear all" style={{fontSize:"15px"}} onClick={this.clearSelected} className="text-danger fa fa-ban pull-right"></i>: ""}</a></li>
        {list}
      </ul>
    </div>
  }
});
```

**ListItem.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

module.exports = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    this.props.whenItemClicked(this.props.item);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <li onClick={this.handleClick} className={this.props.className}>
      <a>{this.props.item}</a>
    </li>
  }
});
```

**DropDownButton.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <button  onClick={this.props.whenClicked} className="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" type="button">
      <span className="filter-option pull-left">{this.props.title}</span>
      <span className="bs-caret"><i className="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
    </button>
  }
});
```

Advance thanks to the one who helps me. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this error exist: "Invariant Violation: Cannot update during an existing state transition"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420402/why-does-this-error-exist-invariant-violation-cannot-update-during-an-existin)

Comment: I think you didn't seen my whole problem. Please see the code once. I didn't called any illegal setState() function as of my knowledge. @TheReason

Comment: It is very strange (and possibly illegal) to call some function on your parent inside `render()`. What does `this.props.ifListChanged(this)` do?

Comment: I just want to send the state of the childComopnent to it's parentComponent. But when I'm using it inside the handleItemClick() previous state is being sent. @wintvelt

Comment: What does the parent do with the filtered list you send up? My guess: that function triggers another render of the parent, so also render of child, and react does not allow that. This would be a prop/state design issue in your setup.

Comment: Here what I'm developed is a multiselect dropdown. I am just sending all selected elements to parentComponent. I've tried sending selectedItems[] array in handleItemClick function (not in state). But it's sending some anonymous data which has been converted to a object. But I don't know how to send a array through a function to it's parentComponent. @wintvelt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a prop/state design issue. Your `this.props.ifListChanged(this)` inside your render function is very suspicious.  Your render function should NOT need to signal anything to parent. Parent already knows all the props it sent down, and if parent needs to know about the state, then it most likely should not be state in the first place.

From what I can gather from your code,

- your List component receives an unfiltered list of items as props
- and it has a state that keeps track of filtereditems and of selecteditems.

This is a nice setup if the result of both need to be sent somewhere *with another action inside the component itself* (e.g. a process-selection button or something).
Then (and only then) would you send the state to parent or to somewhere else.

If the parent needs to know about both *all the time* (for instance when the process-button or process-action is somewhere else), then it is better to:

- define some `handleFilterUpdate` and 'handleSelectionUpdate` methods inside the parent and pass these as props to the child.
- also pass the filtered list and selection from the parent to the child.
- call the `this.props.handleFilterUpdate` and 'this.props.handleSelectionUpdate` from the child whenever something happens with selection or filters.

Comment: I've tried putting it in the other functions and explicitly calling the function. But when I'm calling it. It is passing old state of it. 
Suppose I have clicked on ITEM1, it is sending empty array[].
Next I have clicked on ITEM2, it is sending array [ITEM1]. @wintvelt

Comment: Well, all I can say is that your setup in this question is not a desirable direction to go. With the callback functions, react should not send the previous array up. But that is a whole different question.

Comment: Can you help me with this problem @wintvelt

Comment: Sure, if you post a new question on SO, with code where you make call (apparently with wrong array). If you post a link to new question here in comment, then I will pick it up from there.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296512/react-is-sending-old-state-to-its-parent** this is the new link