# React is sending old state to its parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

When I'm sending state of the child component to its parent component, React is sending old state to the parent component.

I want to send the updated state on every click on ListItem which is properly working and calling the function handleItemClick.

But when I'm calling `sendStateToParent`. It is passing old state of it. Suppose I have clicked on `ITEM1`, it is sending empty array`[]`. Next I have clicked on `ITEM2`, it is sending array `[ITEM1]`.

Here I'm actually creating a multiselect dropdown. which also can act as single select based on props it is getting.

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItemComponent from './ListItem.jsx';
import DropDownButtonComponent from './DropDownButton.jsx';
import DropDownStyle from '../../../../css/sass/drop-down.scss';

module.exports = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function () {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  },
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      open: false,
      //listItems: this.props.listItems,
      selectedItems:[],
      title: this.props.dropdownTitle
    }
  },
  handleItemClick: function (item) {
    var selectedItems = [];
    if(this.props.multiple == true){
      selectedItems = this.state.selectedItems;
      if(selectedItems.indexOf(item)==-1){
        selectedItems.push(item);
      }else{
        selectedItems.splice(selectedItems.indexOf(item),1)
      }
      this.setState({
        title: this.state.selectedItems.length+" selected",
        selectedItems: selectedItems
      });
    } else{
      selectedItems = [];
      selectedItems.push(item);
      this.setState({
        title: item,
        selectedItems: selectedItems,
        open: false
      });
    }
    this.sendStateToParent();
  },
  sendStateToParent: function(){
    this.props.ifListChanged(this);
  },
  handleTextChange: function (event) {
    var filteredItems = [];
    this.props.listItems.map(function(item){
      if(item.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) != -1){
        filteredItems.push(item);
      }
    },this);
    this.setState({
      listItems: filteredItems
    });
  },
  clearSelected: function(){
    this.setState({
      title: this.props.dropdownTitle,
      selectedItems: [],
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    var index = 0;
    var list=[];
    if (this.state.listItems != undefined) {
      list = this.state.listItems.map(function (item) {
        return (
          <ListItemComponent
            key={index++}
            item={item}
            whenItemClicked={this.handleItemClick}
            className={this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item) != -1 ? "active" : ""}
          />);
      }.bind(this));
    } else {
      list = this.props.listItems.map(function (item) {
        return (
          <ListItemComponent
            key={index++}
            item={item}
            whenItemClicked={this.handleItemClick}
            className={this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item) != -1 ? "active" : ""}
          />);
      }.bind(this));
    }

    return <div className="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
      <DropDownButtonComponent
        whenClicked={this.handleClick}
        title={this.state.title}
      />
      <ul className={"dropdown-menu inner dropdown-menu " + (this.state.open ? "show" : "") }>
        {this.props.search? <li><input type="text" style={{margin:"auto", maxWidth:"96%"}} onChange={this.handleTextChange} placeholder="Search"/></li> :""}
        <li className="disabled"><a>Select from below list {this.props.multiple ? <i title="clear all" style={{fontSize:"15px"}} onClick={this.clearSelected} className="text-danger fa fa-ban pull-right"></i>: ""}</a></li>
        {list}
      </ul>
    </div>
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason parent gets the old value of selecteditems, is because `setState()` is an asynchronous operation. See [explanation here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

So in your code, you send a request to update state, and **before the new state is processed**, you call the method in the parent, to inform parent about state, which still has the old items.

**Fix 1:** send current state to parent.
To get the item to send the current state, you could use the callback that `setState()` provides. Explained also in react pages:

> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be
>   executed once `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered.

This ensures that the call to parent is made only after `setState()` is finished. Something like this:

```
this.setState(
  {
    title: item,
    selectedItems: selectedItems,
    open: false
  },
  this.sendStateToParent
);
```

**Fix 2**(optional but recommended): move selecteditems state to parent.
If your parent needs to know about selecteditems, I would advise not to put these in state of the list. The only thing your component does with the selecteditems is to send them to the parent, every time an item is clicked.
Instead, it is better to:

- put selectedItems in state of the parent
- from the parent, pass selectedItems as props to the component
- move the `handleItemClick` logic to the parent
- inside the parent, you update the list of selectedItems, and set state (of the parent)
- triggering a re-render of the list, with the new selectedItems as props