# Why is my state update overwriting existing data values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below I am trying to take a copy of the current state of the users data, along with a copy of a new invoice template pulled from a json file that has the key value pairs all blank.

I then change the templates invoiceID to be 1 more than the idx (this is a number value sent from a child component that is the length of all the invoices in state).

Lastly, I take the copy of the users data and add on the new template, then save that new users data back into state so it can be updated within my list.

```
  createInvoice = idx => {
    let newUserData = this.state.userData;
    let template = UsersJSON[0].invoices[0];

    template.invoiceID = idx + 1;
    newUserData.invoices.push(template);

    this.setState({
      userData: newUserData
    });
  }
```

This is the current state of all the data when I log in:
[image]

After I click New Invoice + once:
[image]

The problem starts happening after I click New Invoice + more than once:
[image]

ONLY all of the NEW Invoice ID's keep being updated to the latest and greatest IDs. I seriously have no clue why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated!

A link to my project on github (look on the invoices branch, not master):
https://github.com/Brent-W-Anderson/invoice-pdf/tree/invoices

Comment: I think we'd benefit from a wider view into your app. It's generally not adequate to link us out.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37297950/1264804 for some insight into setState's async nature.

Comment: Sure thing. The JSON (line 2 -> 39): https://github.com/Brent-W-Anderson/invoice-pdf/blob/invoices/src/data/users.json The App.jsx (where the function is called line 103 -> 113) https://github.com/Brent-W-Anderson/invoice-pdf/blob/invoices/src/components/app.js The invoice.jsx (child component where the onClick handler is called line 162) https://github.com/Brent-W-Anderson/invoice-pdf/blob/master/src/components/pages/invoices/invoices.jsx

Comment: In your question, please. Not down here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

1. You are not correctly creating a new array reference for state and react reconciliation.
2. You are also mutating your template reference object.

Code

```
createInvoice = idx => {
  let newUserData = this.state.userData; // <-- saved state reference
  let template = UsersJSON[0].invoices[0];

  template.invoiceID = idx + 1; // <-- template mutation
  newUserData.invoices.push(template); // <-- mutated state

  this.setState({
    userData: newUserData // <-- saved state reference back into state
  });
}
```

## Solution

Create a shallow copy of all state you intend to update.

```
createInvoice = idx => {
  let newInvoices = [...this.state.userData.invoices]; // <-- create a new array reference
  let template = {
    ...UsersJSON[0].invoices[0], // <-- create new template object reference
  };

  template.invoiceID = idx + 1;
  newInvoices.push(template);

  this.setState({
    userData: {
      ...state.userData,
      invoices: newInvoices,
    }
  });
}
```

A slightly more react-y way to add to state is to map the data from the previous state and spread in the template so you are also not mutating *it*.

```
createInvoice = idx => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    userData: {
      ...prevState.userData,
      invoices: [
        ...prevState.userData.invoices,
        {
          ...UsersJSON[0].invoices[0],
          invoiceID: idx + 1,
        },
      ],
    },
  }));
}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but it's saying that I can't iterate through my ...prevState.userData (I'm assuming it's because this is an object and ...prevState.userData.invoices is the array we can iterate through?)

Comment: @BrentAnderson Ah, quite right, `userData` is an object that needs the `invoices` array copied, sorry for the mixup. I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Wow thanks for all of the help! I didn't think I was directly mutating my state like that since I was copying it into a variable. Is there a way to get the non react-y solution to work? It's throwing that inerrable error for that one.

Comment: @BrentAnderson Yup, sorry, same issue, I didn't reach deep enough for the array copy. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy a state object (and in JS arrays are objects) before updating it. Maybe `let newUserData = [...this.state.userData]` would be the way to avoid this bug, but you might need a 'deep copy.'

See https://dev.to/andyrewlee/cheat-sheet-for-updating-objects-and-arrays-in-react-state-48np for more on this topic.