# React Native: setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, react-native

I'm getting this error upon adding a form validation to my registration form component in React Native.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Form, Item, Input, Label, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
import axios from 'axios';
import { JWT } from 'App';

class RegistrationForm extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   name: '',
   email: '',
   emailValidate: '',
   pin: '',
   pinValidate: '',
   role: 'Consumer',
   pin_confirmation: ''
  };
 }

 onSubmit = () => {
  const { name, email, pin, role, pin_confirmation } = this.state;
  axios
   .post('http://0.0.0.0:4000/api/v1/sign_up', {
    user: {
     name,
     email,
     pin,
     role,
     pin_confirmation
    }
   })
   .then(response => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('JWT', response.data.jwt);
    console.log(response.data.jwt);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
   })
   .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
   });
 };

 validate(text, type) {
  alph = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/g;
  if (type == 'email') {
   if (alph.test(text)) {
    this.setState((emailValidate = true));
   } else {
    this.setState((emailValidate = false));
   }
  }
  return type;
 }

 acceptTextInput = () => {
  if (emailValidate == true) {
   this.setState({ email: type });
  }
 };

 // this.setState({someField:someValue})

 render() {
  return (
   <View>
    <Form>
     <Item floatingLabel>
      <Label>Name</Label>
      <Input
       value={this.state.name}
       onChangeText={name => {
        this.setState({ name });
       }}
      />
     </Item>
     <Item floatingLabel last>
      <Label>Email</Label>
      <Input
       autoCapitalize="none"
       value={this.acceptTextInput}
       onChangeText={text => this.validate(text, 'email')}
      />
     </Item>
     <Item floatingLabel last>
      <Label>Pin</Label>
      <Input
       keyboardType={'number-pad'}
       secureTextEntry
       value={this.state.pin}
       onChangeText={pin => {
        this.setState({ pin });
       }}
      />
     </Item>
     <Item floatingLabel last>
      <Label>Pin Confirmation</Label>
      <Input
       keyboardType={'number-pad'}
       secureTextEntry
       value={this.state.pin_confirmation}
       onChangeText={pin_confirmation => {
        this.setState({ pin_confirmation });
       }}
      />
     </Item>
    </Form>
    <Button onPress={this.onSubmit}>
     <Text> Submit</Text>
    </Button>
   </View>
  );
 }
}

export default RegistrationForm;
```

This is my registration form component. I call a validate function on onChangeText in the Email input. The validate function evaluates if the input in the Email form passes the regex expression. If yes, then  the key 'emailValidate' in state is set to true. I then pass another function called acceptTextInput on the value of the Email input. The acceptTextInput evaluates if emailValidate is equal to true, and if it is, it sets the user input to the email state. For some reason, I'm getting this error & I really don't know why.

**Hope i'm explaining this as clearly as I can**.

Comment: `this.setState((emailValidate = true))` - you need to replace the equal sign with a colon here.

Comment: hey @AlexeyLebedev thanks for the reply. Like this you mean: this.setState((emailValidate = true));

Comment: this.setState({emailValidate : true})

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I have another problem I'm currently experiencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827646/react-native-form-field-validation-unable-to-create-password-validation-for-p  Would be great if someone could help out @AlexeyLebedev

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this error exist: "Invariant Violation: Cannot update during an existing state transition"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420402/why-does-this-error-exist-invariant-violation-cannot-update-during-an-existin)