# React Native - Form Field Validation: Unable to create password validation for password confirmation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, react-native

I'm building a pin validation in the registration form to check  if the first pin matches the second one. I created a validatePinConfirmation function that checks whether pin is equal to pin_confirmation. If it is then we set the state of pin_confirmation to the value inserted by the user. For some reason, the function or the form is not passing the value through and saving it to the DB. I would really appreciate if someone could point what I'm doing wrong exactly.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Form, Item, Input, Label, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
import axios from 'axios';
import { JWT } from 'App';

class RegistrationForm extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   name: '',
   email: '',
   emailValidate: '',
   pin: '',
   pinValidate: '',
   role: 'Consumer',
   pin_confirmation: ''
  };
 }

 validateEmail(text, type) {
  alph = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/g;
  if (type == 'email') {
   if (alph.test(text)) {
    this.setState({ emailValidate: true });
   } else {
    this.setState({ emailValidate: false });
   }
  }
  if ({ emailValidate: true }) {
   this.setState({ email: text });
  }
 }

 validatePinConfirmation(text) {
  const { pin, pin_confirmation } = this.state;
  if (text == pin) {
   this.setState({ pinValidate: true });
  } else {
   this.setState({ pinValidate: false });
  }
  if ({ pinValidate: true }) {
   this.setState({ pin_confirmation });
  }
 }

 onSubmit = () => {
  const { name, email, pin, role, pin_confirmation } = this.state;
  axios
   .post('http://0.0.0.0:4000/api/v1/sign_up', {
    user: {
     name,
     email,
     pin,
     role,
     pin_confirmation
    }
   })
   .then(response => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('JWT', response.data.jwt);
    console.log(response.data.jwt);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
   })
   .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
   });
 };

 render() {
  return (
   <View>
    <Form>
     <Item floatingLabel>
      <Label>Name</Label>
      <Input
       value={this.state.name}
       onChangeText={name => {
        this.setState({ name });
       }}
      />
     </Item>
     <Item floatingLabel last>
      <Label>Email</Label>
      <Input
       autoCapitalize="none"
       value={this.state.email}
       onChangeText={text => this.validateEmail(text, 'email')}
      />
     </Item>
     <Item floatingLabel last>
      <Label>Pin</Label>
      <Input
       keyboardType={'number-pad'}
       secureTextEntry
       value={this.state.pin}
       onChangeText={pin => {
        this.setState({ pin });
       }}
      />
     </Item>
     <Item floatingLabel last>
      <Label>Pin Confirmation</Label>
      <Input
       keyboardType={'number-pad'}
       secureTextEntry
       value={this.state.pin_confirmation}
       onChangeText={text => this.validatePinConfirmation(text)}
      />
     </Item>
    </Form>
    <Button onPress={this.onSubmit}>
     <Text> Submit</Text>
    </Button>
   </View>
  );
 }
}

export default RegistrationForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<Input
    keyboardType={'number-pad'}
    secureTextEntry
    value={this.state.pin_confirmation}
    onChangeText={this.validatePinConfirmation.bind(this)}
/>
```

The context of `this` is out of the scope you want to use. Let me know if that works. You might have to do the same for `onSubmit` as well.

Comment: @isProf Thanks for the comment. I did what you said but now the simulator is telling me pin_confirmation is undefined. I tried passing pin_confirmation as an argument to validatePinConfirmation function but it didn't work. What do you think I should do?

Comment: @AlyDabbous check all the functions that access `this` that are being passed as callbacks. They all need to get the context minded using `bind(this)`.

Comment: @isProf I don't understand can you please elaborate more? :) Thank you!

Comment: Would not it be better calling `bind()` just once somewhere in constructor? Making this in template will return new function so `Input` will be re-rendered alongside any change in its parent container.

Answer (score 0):

this inside function created with function keyword is undefined & that's the issue you face you have two options

1. use .bind() function this.validatePinConfirmation.bind(this)
2. use arrow function for example validatePinConfirmation should be defined as flow

   validatePinConfirmation = (text) => { /* your code */} // this here isn't undefined since arrow function retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's this

you can get more about this from this [blog post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context)

Answer (score 0):

Alongside other suggestions fix your check

```
if ({ emailValidate: true }) {
```

this always be executed since any object is converted to boolean value of `true`.
I believe you need to check for something like

```
if (this.state.emailValidate) {
```

but this actually will not work because `.setState()` is [async operation](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0?gi=cb3c38b9ed95). That is: calling `.setState` does not change state immediately.
So you better introduce interm variable and check it:

```
let isEmailValid = true;
...
this.setState({emailValidate: isEmailValid});
if (isEmailValid) {
    this.setState({email: text});
```