# Error: setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

It's giving me error in else part `this.state.incorrect + 1` and `this.state.correct + 1`

I have seen this but not solve my problem [React Native: setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821777/react-native-setstate-takes-an-object-of-state-variables-to-update-or-a-f)

```
if (choice == this.state.dataset[this.state.current].correct) {
            this.setState(this.state.correct + 1)
        } else {
            this.setState(this.state.incorrect + 1)
        }
```

Comment: i think you need to send an object with key and value to setState

Comment: Please post some more code to better understand the problem.

Comment: @AnkitaKuchhadiya my problem solved by DILEEPTHOMAS Thank you!

Comment: @shivlalkumavat I have also posted an answer in detail for more knowledge you can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In react the `setState` takes an object or an async function. You are using neither of them. In your case, If you need to update the state value you need to use

```
this.setState({correct: this.state.correct + 1});
```

Also be careful when you use that way of setting the state value because `setState` is async operation and you will might not guarantee to get the value of the state variable immediately. If you want to use the value of the `setState()` then use a async callback with `setState`

```
  this.setState({correct: this.state.correct + 1}, function() {
     // you get the new value of state immediately at this callback
  });
```

Comment: Okay, I got, Thank you!

Comment: @shivlalkumavat happy to help

Answer (score 2):

you need to update the state, since state you defined is an object. And you need to tell which property of the object you are updating as shown below.

```
if (choice == this.state.dataset[this.state.current].correct) {
            this.setState({correct: this.state.correct + 1})
        } else {
            this.setState({incorrect: this.state.incorrect + 1})
        }
```

Doc [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

**Update**

As  @titus updated on the comments proper way is as shown below, since react gaves the prevState object which has the prev State of the component.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({correct: prevState.correct + 1}))
```

Comment: When the new state is derived from the previous one, you should use `setState` with a function as the first parameter, eg: `this.setState(prevState => ({correct: prevState.correct + 1}))`

Comment: Is there any diff of using prevState.correct and this.state.correct since the state didn't updated @Titus

Comment: @shivlalkumavat happy to help, kindly accept if it worked for you :)

Comment: There is an explanation for that [HERE](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: So currently setState can be async and sync isn't because when we set a state inside a promise level it will be sync and in normal event handlers it will be an async so this will be changed i react 17 by the use of concurrent mode, is this is correct @Titus

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `setState` is not a promise, it is just async and newer version of React use **hooks** and **effects** instead of `setState`.